# Ad-hoc communication (messaging) system over Android

Tags: android, communication, xmpp, messaging, adhoc

I am looking for the feasibility of implementing an ad-hoc type messaging service on Android. Basically I want a several Android users to be able to communicate (text is enough at this point) without having a cellular connection. But there can be a centralized access point. For example a low-power computer with a wireless router.

What is the best way to implement something like this? I was thinking using XMPP. Could use the computer as the XMPP server and let Android users connect to it. Is this a reasonable approach?

Any suggestions are greatly welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: By "without having a cellular connection", do you mean you'll have a wifi connection? Also, If they connected through an XMPP server, that wouldn't be ad-hoc

Comment: Do you need that computer in the middle?  If you want ad-hoc there are only two options as I see it.  Bluetooth and direct connection via wifi - no computer.

Comment: By adhoc I meant that it will have a centralized access point. But it will be mobile as in that central computer will be movable. There will be a wifi connection by the wifi router connected to that central computer. It would good if I can do without a central computer and router, but that wouldn't give me much range in that case. Cheers.

Comment: This is **not** ad-hoc. In ad-hoc you communicate without a central point, and possibly via other users.

Answer (score 2):

Adhoc and XMPP fit together in this context as follows: the network connections between the phones are adhoc; [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html) defines client to client server-less messaging. Two issues need be solved:

1) The adhoc Android connections - not clear to me if this is generally [possible](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82)

2) Finding an XMPP Android client library that supports the xep-0174 protocols. The Smack library supports this, and I think it currently runs in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a centralized access point, it is straight forward, you open a socket connection between the different devices and exchange the data you need. I am not sure why you call it ad hoc though.